# How to hide/show only the selected form based on click event of a link, out of multiple forms with same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple forms with links to toggle them being appended to a page after a certain action. I want each link that is associated with each form to toggle it's own form  show/hide.

So far what I have is this but jquery returning some prevObject which doesn't work.

This is included at the end in the function that is contains the code which appends the html to the page after action.

```
$("#flatbanstart").on('click', flatbanstarts);
```

This is the function to try to show/hide a form based on if it's already shown or hidden, if its shown ,then hide, etc. Each link with id 'flatbanstart should show/hide it's own form/closest form. form and that link are inside a div together.

```
function flatbanstarts(e){

var currform = $(this).find('.flatbanform');
console.log(currform);


if((currform.offsetWidth == 0) && (currform.offsetHeight == 0)){

  console.log(currform.offsetWidth + "durhelo");
  currform.show();
}else{
  console.log(currform.offsetWidth + "durheloHIDE");
  currform.hide();
}


}
```

jquery return this ;(

```
n.fn.init [prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: a#flatbanstart.flatbanstart, selector: ".flatbanform"]
index.js:247 undefineddurheloHIDE
```

EDIT: Ok I updated to this but now it's just showing/hiding the first form only. the other links don't work. ;/

```
function flatbanstarts(e){

var currform = $(this).parent().find('.flatbanform');
console.log(currform);


if(currform.is(':visible')){

  console.log(currform.is(':visible'));
  currform.hide();
}else{
  console.log(currform.is(':visible')+"dfs");
  currform.show();
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find will stop after it finds the first html element with the class "flatbanform", that's why only your first form will hide and show.

You could do something like this. Select $(this) when you click on the class, and to that selected element you can add a class name, something like: hide-form and in css hide-form will have: display: none;

After this you can just play with addClass('hide-form') and removeclass('hide-form') to hide or display the elements.

Comment: this refers to the link i click on. Why would i add that hide-form class to it? i need it added to the form, which is below the link. i need the link to always be visible but the form to be shown/hidden on click of that link.

Comment: ID's across your html should be **unique**, don't use the same ID sever times. Instead if you want only 1 function to do it all, put the click event on the class. After with $(this).find('.form') try to hide/show it depending if it's visible or not.

Comment: i think you and i just got it at the same time LOL. Good catch though =D

Comment: haah yeah. Good luck and happy coding @user3542679

Answer (score 0):

The issue was this:

```
$("#flatbanstart").on('click', flatbanstarts);
```

I changed it to:

```
$(".flatbanstart").on('click', flatbanstarts);
```

considering I can't have all the same id's on the same page. Must be classes.

Cya kappaflow! =) Genius OUT!
P.S thnx for the suggestions though Robert, got my thinking going better =D